# Google Datastore multiple parents?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

Can an entity have multiple parents that don't go in a single line like son->father->grandfather?

Examples:

Family tree: Mom & Dad are both parents of all their children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, an entity can only have a single parent. From [Ancestor paths](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths):

> Entities in Cloud Datastore form a hierarchically structured space
>   similar to the directory structure of a file system. When you create
>   an entity, you can optionally designate another entity as its
>   *parent*; the new entity is a *child* of the parent entity (note that unlike in a file system, the parent entity need not actually exist).
>   An entity without a parent is a *root entity*. The association between
>   an entity and its parent is permanent, and cannot be changed once the
>   entity is created. Cloud Datastore will never assign the same numeric
>   ID to two entities with the same parent, or to two root entities
>   (those without a parent).
>
> An entity's parent, parent's parent, and so on recursively, are its
>   *ancestors*; its children, children's children, and so on, are its *descendants*. The sequence of entities beginning with a root entity and proceeding from parent to child, leading to a given entity,
>   constitute that entity's *ancestor path*. The complete key identifying
>   the entity consists of a sequence of kind-identifier pairs specifying
>   its ancestor path and terminating with those of the entity itself:
>
> ```
> [User:alice, TaskList:default, Task:sampleTask]
> ```
>
> For a root entity, the ancestor path is empty and the key consists
>   solely of the entity's own kind and identifier:
>
> ```
> [User:alice]
> ```

Following the directory structure comparison: a file can only exist in one directory, not in two or more.

Comment: I thought about the directory structure part. I figured "A file can symbolically be in two folders at once with a sym link..." ... Thanks!

Comment: Except in that case what exists in the 2nd dir is not the file itself, but the symlink - which is a different (special) file.